# .NET 4.5 - Where is my security.cfg

Tags: .net, security

I'm just a guy that's trying to add security information for an application in `security.cfg` and I know nothing about `.Net` and I've a problem to understand the `.Net v4.5`

After searching to Internet I find the command below, but it seems to have no effect for application that use `.Net 4.5.`

```
 caspol -machine -addgroup All_Code -site ***** FullTrust -name "******"
```

In fact, I need to execute the command under : `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\caspol`, but I haven't the version 4.5 but v4.0.30319.
In my windows registry I have in `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"` the version 4.5.50709

And It's not an option to install the SDK. 
To conclude, how can I execute the command caspol for `.Net 4.5`, if I haven't 4.5 directory under  `"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"` ?

Comment: I'd review [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/199134/caspol-and-net-configuration-tool) which directs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233103%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). CAS changed a lot in the later versions. I'm not sure what version you are coming from, but the story may have changed a lot for you. I personally don't use it so I can't really offer any truly informed answers, just a general awareness that stuff isn't the same anymore.

Comment: This is an XY Problem.  .NET 4.5 does **not** add a new version of the runtime.  It just added a bunch of new assemblies.  So the caspol.exe you found in the v4.0.30319 directory is the correct one.  Review [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx) to find proper caspol.exe usage.

Comment: Thank you for the precision. I restart my research to understand why the command seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The version 4.5.50709 in the windows registry means that you have .Net 4.5 installed.

Your problem is not the .Net version.

[How to: View Security Policy Using Caspol.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yfz2s7ya%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)